# Cycling through lines obtained by vim's :g

Tags: vim

I'm using the `:g` command in vim. Is there a way to directly jump (one after another, similar to `:cn`) to the lines found by `:g`?

`:h :g` does not seem to contain such facilities.

Comment: Use `:%s/pattern/replacement/gc`. `:g` seems to be the wrong tool for the job, here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it depends on what did you do with the `:g`.

if your `:g` command didn't change the matched pattern, you could press `n` to go to next matched line.

but if you changed the pattern, e.g. you did `:g/foo/d` or `:g/foo/s/foo/bar/g`, those lines won't be there after you fire your `:g` command. then there is no way to reach those line again.

Comment: Maybe hes using the default behaviour of `:g` which is `p` and just wants to cycle through the lines that were printed? (which would be your second line)

Answer (score 2):

The usual way of jumping successively to the matches of a pattern would be to use normal search , not the global command. This is, `/<pattern>`, and then `n` for successive matches.

The global command `:g` is used to run another command on a **non-contiguous set of lines**. For a contiguous set of lines, a range is enough. Ex: `:1,5<command>`.

But, if for some reason you need to use the global command, or just for the record, there's a way to do what you want using `:g`.

From Vim's help:

```
When using "global" in Ex mode, a special case is using ":visual" as a
command.  This will move to a matching line, go to Normal mode to let you
execute commands there until you use |Q| to return to Ex mode.  This will be
repeated for each matching line.  While doing this you cannot use ":global".
To abort this type CTRL-C twice.
```

To see the full story, `:h multi-repeat`.

So, step by step, it would be:

- Enter ex mode (Press `Q`).

  This is like command-line mode, but you don't go back to normal mode after command execution, and you don't  have to type the leading `:`. To go back to normal mode from here, `:visual` is used.
- Run global command executing `:visual` subcommand. This is, `:g/<pattern>/visual`.

  That will send you into normal mode for each match. Each time, you can use all vim's power to do whatever you want with that match and, when finished, going back to ex mode (pressing `Q` again) continues with the next match.
- When you're finished with last match, you will be left in ex mode again. Enter `:visual` to go back to normal mode then.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want, you could simply use `:grep` or `:vimgrep` instead of `:g`, which will put the matching lines into the quickfix list. (use the l variations of the commands for filling the location list).